# DateTime variable in Pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to solve production planning problem using pulp. Every order in the list has expected delivery date and my objective is to minimize order tardiness.

Below are my variables:

• x(ij) is the integer start time of job j on machine i.

• z(ijk) is equal to 1 if job j precedes job k on machine i.

I want to minimize:

```
deldt[j,m]-x[(j,m)]
```

where deldt[j,m] is order delivery date.

When I create model like below:

```
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("time", [(j,m) for j,m in order.index], lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')   
prob += lpSum(deldt[j,m]-x[(j,m)] for i,l in order.index)
```

I get ValueError:

> ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.

I think this is because x is integer and not DateTime.
Is there any way to overcome this problem.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with PuLP but if you're working with integers, shouldn't you be using an integer variable instead of time?

Comment: I want to work with datetime variable if possible, since I want to minimize delay.

Comment: then convert x into a datetime. Else you can convert the date into a integer. Your choice ^^

Comment: Obviously LPs and MIPs only know about binary, integer and continuous variables.

Comment: Yes but if I create one binary variable for each day and each order, I will have more than 20000 variables, is there a better way than this to solve the problem.